# The game of Brussels Sprouts

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I read once about a variant of the game Sprouts called Brussels Sprouts.  Instead of placing dots on a plane, one places $n$ $+$ signs instead.  Each player, in turn, connects any two free legs, either on the same $+$ sign or on different signs, but moves that would cross a pre-existing line (or $+$ sign) are not permitted.  A new hash mark is drawn normal to the newly drawn line, providing two new free legs.  The game ends when a player cannot move -- the other player is then declared the winner.

The name is a deliberate joke.  That's because, according to the article I read, no matter what moves are made, each game will always have exactly $5n-2$ moves.  I have no idea how to prove this but it seems to be correct for the examples I checked.

Does anyone know how to prove this claim?

Comment: There is a proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprouts_(game)#Brussels_Sprouts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by David, the proof for this particular problem can be found on the [Wikipedia page for the game Sprouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprouts_(game)#Brussels_Sprouts). For completeness, I have included their proof below:

> Let $m$ denote the number of moves and $v$, $e$, $f$ denote the number of vertices, edges, and faces of the planar graph obtained at the end of the game, respectively. We have:
>
> - $e = 2m$ since at each move, the player adds two edges.
> - $v = n + m$ since at each move, the player adds one vertex and the game starts with $n$ vertices.
> - $f = 4n$ since there is exactly one free end in each face at the end of the game, and the number of free ends does not change during the game.
>
> The **Euler characteristic for planar graphs** is $2$, so:
> $$ 2 = f+v-e = 5n - m \space \iff m = 5n - 2$$

Thus, proving the hypothesis.